# Problems with GLTF export of animations since version 3.1

Tags: animation, export, gltf

I have built a simple animation, coins that dance up and down while rotating around their own axis. The coins are parented directly to the bones. In Blender this works without any problems.

Then I exported the blend file with Blender 3.2 as gltf and the animation now looks completely different. The rotations are around a different center point.

When I export this animation with Blender 3.0 everything is fine, but since version 3.1 it doesn't work anymore.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

I have filed a bug report on the Blender forum. The bug is fixed as of version 3.4

For the current version 3.3.1 (and versions 3.1 and 3.2) there is a workaround.
The Blender file is exported correctly if you enable the "Use Current Frame" option.

[image: Use Current Frame option]